# Black Screen on Startup

Tags: boot

I've been running on Linux for only about a week now. But I just came back to my PC after using it last night and now it won't boot properly. When I try to boot it asks for my crypt password so I enter it, then it shows the Ubuntu loading bar, then it flicks to a black screen with white text for about 3 seconds that reads:

"Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS bchastko-MS-7693 tty1

bchastko-MS-7693 login: "

Then that text disappears and leaves me with a black screen until I turn off my computer. Ctrl+alt+del does not work once I'm at this screen. I've tried Boot Repair but it had no effect. The URL is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12717798/. If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

### here's your problem:

```
=================== blkid:
/dev/sda3: UUID="f18a769e-4f52-49ad-a38e-bab773834ad8" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"


mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
mount /dev/sda3 : Error code 32
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
mount -r /dev/sda3 : Error code 32
```

### ermm...

at this point, you'll probably need to load up a live cd, and mount your lukscrypt partition there, with the decryption key.

you're going to need to use /dev/mapper for mounting sda3 in your fstab/mount commands.

At this point, I suspect, you're going to need to boot to a live Ubuntu CD, `chroot` the Ubuntu environment, mount all the partitions on all the drives, and run grub-update.  This process should both recover the boot for Windows and Linux to the grub menu.

Try the following:

1. Boot the Ubuntu LiveDVD
2. Select the option <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>
3. Then try the following:

   ```
   sudo su -
   mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3/ crypthome
   mount /dev/mapper/crypthome /mnt
   ```

   At this point, you'll have mounted your encrypted LUKS partition to `/mnt` on the LiveDVD.

   I would advise saving everything from `/mnt/home` to external storage before continuing.  Worst case, if this becomes too painful, you can start over and at least save any docs/pics/desktop/junk/etc you may have been working on.
4. Now we're going to attempt to fix things... through a chroot

   ```
   mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   ```

   At this stage you'll be in your PC's native OS in a chroot environment, but we're far from clear of your problem:  we're going to need to review things, so your input from here forward will greatly help.
5. copy things that will help us diagnose, your pc should have internet access as well, if not you can place the following things on external storage and paste individually to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ passing the links back to this help topic.

   ```
   /etc/fstab
   /dev/mapper/*
   ```

   - Please update on your progress and pain points. At the moment, it's hard to decypher just what went wrong
   - you're running full disk encryption and the mount point for dev/mapper doesn't appear to be properly set up, so boot is failing...

Comment: Thanks for your response knope! Unfortunately many of these terms are new to me, but I went through a couple of walkthroughs for what you suggested, namely https://alvinabad.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/how-to-recover-a-luks-encrypted-disk/ and https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/how-to-mount-luks-encrypted-partitions-manually/ but going through both I get held-up when they use luksDump and luksOpen. I get an error that reads "Device/sda3/ doesn't exist or access denied." I'm going to keep searching through the web for solutions to that problem, but any tips would be great

Comment: I think I found the solution to the above problem. It seems like for the trouble lines I need to enter "sudo" before the trailing command, not sure why but it leads to the same outcome as the walk-thoughs predict

Comment: i think i posted a solution to your problem else where...  and now i feel dumb lol ... one sec.

Comment: edited solution with steps i think should help you at the very least rescue your system  :)